# How to cancel a job in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I want to make an eclipse plugin that calls an external build tool.
I'm using the CDT `IMakeTarget` because it already provides a framework that does a lot(console handling, parser, error markers, etc.).

The biggest issue I have is that I cannot cancel the job that calls `IMakeTarget.build()` because the external program that is launched contains many time intensive steps which don't react to cancellation requests. If I terminate the thread which creates the job, then the job does terminate but some parts of eclipse stop working, and even then, the external program is still not killed.

Is there a way to forcibly terminate an eclipse job together with whatever is inside it?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite some time that i have not played with Eclipse jobs but as far as I remember, it is not possible.

The plugin creating the job should check for cancellation regularly https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJobs/article.html#handle-job-cancellation

There was some work done to report the ones that are doing doing the check and fix them https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470175

Your solution is to find the job plugin responsible for the job and report an issue (and a patch/merge request/pull request) to have job responsive to the cancellation.